# Создание автоматического всплывающего окна в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть ли способ создать так сказать автоматическое всплывающее окно т.е. при открытии приложении всплывало окошко с пояснением, что нужно сделать в данном блоке.

Скорее всего `setToolTip(str)` мне не сильно поможет т.к. он вроде как только при наводке на окно работает, что не совсем то что мне нужно было бы. 
Если возможен вариант реализации отпишите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляю [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/31329b6ec49a5b2e6248109ca320e185ff29202c/pyqt5_QToolTip_with_programmatically_timeout.py) использования [QToolTip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QTimer


def show_tooltip(parent, widget):
    qtw.QToolTip.showText(parent.mapToGlobal(widget.pos()), widget.toolTip(), widget, QRect())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication([])

    line_edit = qtw.QLineEdit()
    line_edit.setToolTip('This <b>my</b> LINE EDIT!')

    button = qtw.QPushButton('My button!')
    button.setToolTip('Simple button...')

    text_edit = qtw.QTextEdit()
    text_edit.setToolTip('TextEdit!')

    layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
    layout.addRow('Line edit:', line_edit)
    layout.addRow('Button:', button)
    layout.addRow('Text edit:', text_edit)

    w = qtw.QWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle('Tooltip example')
    w.setLayout(layout)
    w.show()

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: show_tooltip(w, line_edit))
    QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: show_tooltip(w, button))
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: show_tooltip(w, text_edit))

    app.exec()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Добавлю [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa6f74fd2e55f2e6e64b3ad9f8851d3129c780d8/pyqt5_QToolTip_with_programmatically_timeout__using_QEvent.py) аналогичной работы, но уже через отправку события к конкретному виджету:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QHelpEvent


def show_tooltip(parent, widget):
    app.notify(widget, QHelpEvent(QHelpEvent.ToolTip, widget.pos(), parent.mapToGlobal(widget.pos())))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication([])

    line_edit = qtw.QLineEdit()
    line_edit.setToolTip('This <b>my</b> LINE EDIT!')

    button = qtw.QPushButton('My button!')
    button.setToolTip('Simple button...')

    text_edit = qtw.QTextEdit()
    text_edit.setToolTip('TextEdit!')

    layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
    layout.addRow('Line edit:', line_edit)
    layout.addRow('Button:', button)
    layout.addRow('Text edit:', text_edit)

    w = qtw.QWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle('Tooltip example')
    w.setLayout(layout)
    w.show()

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: show_tooltip(w, line_edit))
    QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: show_tooltip(w, button))
    QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: show_tooltip(w, text_edit))

    app.exec()
```

---

**PS.** Если при ошибке в слотах приложение просто падает без стека, есть хороший способ ловить такие ошибки:

```
import traceback
import sys

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    qtw.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

Comment: А можно это реализовать так чтобы в конкретной точке было показано это окно?

Comment: А в `QToolTip.showText` первый параметр и есть конкретная точка

Comment: Нее, так работать не будет, а вот так будет: `QPoint(50, 50)`

Comment: Спасибо немного порыскав сам вник что ошибся)